# Spring Boot application in Kotlin starts to answer 404 after some time

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, http-status-code-404

I'm having this problem with a new Spring Boot service, written in Kotlin, where I start to get 404 for any REST requests after some random time (When I deploy the service, instead, everything works fine, with the same REST APIs).
In addition, I've also other services, written in Java, that are running without any problem.

Just to specify:

- all the components are well defined in the application;
- I've moved logging filters and some authorization logic in libraries also used in the java services (services that are running perfectly);
- I am not able to reproduce locally, it happens after some time only in staging and prod envs.

Then I've noticed a really strange thing:

- when running a public request (so that I skip all the auth logic checks) the logger prints the response status as 200 -> but then the final answer that the client gets is 404.

Do you have any idea or tip?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could try enter the service with a debugger when it happens in the staging environment, and step through the code to see exactly what causes the 404?

Comment: @marstran actually I don't know how I can do that. The staging is running in a pod in gcp

Comment: Is your app running on machine you don't have direct control of?  Could it be that the service is being remounted by the container and either installing an old copy of your app or unmounting it altogether?  That would be consistent with 404s.  

I suggest you implement a background activity (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks) that emits some kind of status from the app.  Include a ZonedDateTime set to now() in the class constructor, and emit that too in your log.  This may help you understand if this is some weird hosting behaviour rather than your app.

Comment: depends on how the deployment is done. is it deployed in a web container? on cloud? any API gateway infront of the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed! It was a mistake in the middleware, there were two service without the correct routing setup -> traefik was not able to redirect the traffic in the right way